MySQL: LeetCode 1251. Average Selling Price (15/17 Test Cases Passed)
SELECT p.product_id, 
ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(price * units) / NULLIF(SUM(units), 0), 0), 2) AS average_price
FROM Prices p
JOIN UnitsSold u ON u.product_id = p.product_id
AND u.purchase_date BETWEEN p.start_date AND p.end_date
GROUP BY p.product_id;

Only passes 15/17 test cases, not sure why

Tried using NULLIF, COALESCE function

syntax correct, passes test case in leetcode


This is the problem statement:

Table: Prices

+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| product_id    | int     |
| start_date    | date    |
| end_date      | date    |
| price         | int     |
+---------------+---------+

(product_id, start_date, end_date) is the primary key (combination of columns with unique values) for this table.
Each row of this table indicates the price of the product_id in the period from start_date to end_date.
For each product_id there will be no two overlapping periods. That means there will be no two intersecting periods for the same product_id.
 
Table: UnitsSold

+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| product_id    | int     |
| purchase_date | date    |
| units         | int     |
+---------------+---------+

This table may contain duplicate rows.
Each row of this table indicates the date, units, and product_id of each product sold.
Write a solution to find the average selling price for each product. average_price should be rounded to 2 decimal places.
Return the result table in any order.
The result format is in the following example.
Example 1:

Input: 
Prices table:
+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| product_id | start_date | end_date   | price  |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| 1          | 2019-02-17 | 2019-02-28 | 5      |
| 1          | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-22 | 20     |
| 2          | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-20 | 15     |
| 2          | 2019-02-21 | 2019-03-31 | 30     |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+
UnitsSold table:
+------------+---------------+-------+
| product_id | purchase_date | units |
+------------+---------------+-------+
| 1          | 2019-02-25    | 100   |
| 1          | 2019-03-01    | 15    |
| 2          | 2019-02-10    | 200   |
| 2          | 2019-03-22    | 30    |
+------------+---------------+-------+
Output: 
+------------+---------------+
| product_id | average_price |
+------------+---------------+
| 1          | 6.96          |
| 2          | 16.96         |
+------------+---------------+



/ NULLIF(SUM(units), 0)  is wrong as it would produce an error 0 division

Why not use AVG(price * units)`

@nbk search the question up, you have to divide it by the number of units for 1 product id

No, we don't search the question up. We don't leave this site to go somewhere else to get information needed for your question. It's your responsibility to put all the relevant details here in the question itself. That is required by the [help/on-topic] guidelines, which says that you need to provide a [mre] and clear problem description.

You should still output a product even if it has no entry in the UnitsSold table, so use a left outer join instead of an inner join.
LEFT JOIN UnitsSold u ON u.product_id = p.product_id
AND u.purchase_date BETWEEN p.start_date AND p.end_date


As you can see
For the price you can use 0 as alternative Value for NULL
but for divider you nned to return 1
Final word before this will be deleted, you need only the last query for your test
SELECT p.product_id, 
ROUND(SUM(price * COALESCE(units,0)) / SUM(COALESCE(units,1)),2) AS average_price
FROM Prices p
LEFT JOIN UnitsSold u ON u.product_id = p.product_id
AND u.purchase_date BETWEEN p.start_date AND p.end_date
GROUP BY p.product_id;




product_id
average_price




1
6.96


2
16.96



SELECT p.product_id, 
ROUND(SUM(price * units) / SUM(units),2) AS average_price
FROM Prices p
INNER JOIN UnitsSold u ON u.product_id = p.product_id
AND u.purchase_date BETWEEN p.start_date AND p.end_date
GROUP BY p.product_id;




product_id
average_price




1
6.96


2
16.96



fiddle
